# perform ajax on-click function if the td is not null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom, onclick

currently i have a table that has a image inside the td,i am performing some ajax function to update value in database when the td image is click,my problem was if the td is empty(i.e:no image in the td) it also perform the same function.what i want if the td is empty(i.e: no image in the td)if i click no action will perform only if there is image in td it perform the function,can any one guide me how to do it,thanks

Html:

```
<td style="width:120px" id="CPH_GridView1_Status'.$rows['net_id'].'" class="edit2 status '.$rows["net_id"].' "><img  src="image/'.$rows["status"].'f.png" /></td>
```

ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var onClick, ajaxSuccessHandleMaker;
  onClick = function() {
    var
      url = 'clientnetworkpricelist/updateprice.php',
      clientid = $('#client')[0].value,
      classesArray = $(this).attr('class').split(" "),
      // send data as object, jQuery will transparently transform for the server
      data = {
        value : $('.ajax input').val,
        rowid : classesArray[2],
        field : classesArray[1],
        clientid : clientid
      };
    // send POST request and expect JSON
    $.post(url,data,ajaxSuccessHandleMaker(classesArray),'json');
  };
  // success returns the ajax handler with a closure on classesArray
  ajaxSuccessHandleMaker = function (arr) {
    // the handler EXPECTS an array, which is why we have to protect output in updateprice.php
    return function (arrayOf2vals) {
      $('#CPH_GridView1_clientprice'+arr[2]).html(arrayOf2vals[0]);
      $('#CPH_GridView1_Status'+arr[2]).html(arrayOf2vals[1]);
      // I am not sure what you want with the following 2 lines of code
      $('.ajax').html($(this).val());// what is this?
      $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');// what is this?
    };
  };
  // set the onClick handler
  $('.edit2').click(onClick);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To test if there is an image you could do:

```
// your modified function
onClick = function() {
  var tdElement = $(this);
  if (tdElement.find('img').length > 0) {
    // put your ajax request here....
  }
}
```

or you could trigger the ajax Request from the image itself, and not the td.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.edit2').click(function(){

      var myvar = this.innerHTML;

      if(myvar.length>0) {
        //your code
      }

});
```

Retrieve data by edit2 class... If it is your problem .. use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _html = $('#CPH_GridView1_Status img').attr('src');

 if (_html){
      alert('Image exit');
   // Do your logic
  }
  else{
   alert('image not exit');
  }
```

or

```
 var _html = $('#CPH_GridView1_Status img').length ;

    if (_html > 0 ){
          alert('Image exit');
       // Do your logic
      }
      else{
       alert('image not exit');
      }
```